# Updating value of a variable and ViewChild ElementRef is not working inside setTimeOut() function in .TS file

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am working on an Angular project. I am using loader in the project.

**app.html**

```
<div #loading>
  <app-loader></app-loader>
</div>
```

**app.ts**

```
@ViewChild('loading', {static:false}) loading:ElementRef;
```

If I use the code below, It is working absolutely fine. Console is printing the element.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.loading.nativeElement);
}
```

But if I use it inside the `setTimeOut()` function, In the console I am getting its value as `undefined`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 setTimeout(function () {
   console.log(this.loading.nativeElement);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Why is this so, I am not getting it inside `setTimeOut()` function. If I use a variable `loading=false` and if I update it inside `setTimeOut()` function as `setTimeout(function() {this.loading=false;}, 1000);` the value of loading still not updating there.

I also can use `document.getElementById('loading')` in JavaScript or `$("#loading").css("display", "none");` in JQuery. But I don't have to. I want to use it only in type script, neither in java script nor in JQuery.

Please let me know If any one know the way to access an element in `setTimeOut()` function in pure Typescript.

Comment: seem to be like a life cycle issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll want to use "fat arrow function" syntax instead. [It does not create it's own bindings to `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which allows you to access variables in your component easily.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(this.loading.nativeElement);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
           console.log(this.loading.nativeElement);
        },1000);
}
```